# Unable to add margin between items in horizontal RecycleView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I use horizontal `RecyclerView`, the margin between my list item is constant, I want to increase the list item gap, I tried increasing the `layout_margin` but there is no change.

Below is my list item layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="30dp"
android:background="@color/colorWhite"
app:cardElevation="2dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Sample title"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextBlack"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:textColor="#9f9f9f"
        android:text="2 Aug, London" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

This is the view I am getting, I want to increase the gap between the items
[image]

can someone help me with the issue?

Comment: Apply `padding_right` for `CardView`. Also you can use `ItemDecorator`.

Comment: check this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543420/7666442

Comment: @NileshRathod I tried that answer, still for the first item in the list margin is not set

Comment: @AmruthaSaj m make `Linear layout1 parent of ``cardview` than set padding to linear layout try that

Comment: @NileshRathod yes it worked.

Comment: @AmruthaSaj enjoy codding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your XML like this and can try,

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:background="@color/colorAccent"
           app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
           app:cardElevation="2dp"
           app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
           app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/itemImage"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/itemImage"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="Sample title"
            android:textColor="@color/cardview_dark_background"
            android:textSize="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="2 Aug, London"
            android:textColor="#9f9f9f"
            android:textSize="12dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(),
            DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
```

For customizing it a little bit you can add a custom drawable:

```
DividerItemDecoration itemDecorator = new DividerItemDecoration(new 
DividerItemDecoration(getActivity(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
itemDecorator.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), 
R.drawable.divider));
```

divider.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
<solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
<size android:height="0.5dp"/> //change height acc to your need.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add some padding to your cardview in list item layout.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```