# How can I make a gridview by separating rows and columns?

Tags: android, gridview

how to generate an interface as the image shows using a gridview[image]

As you can see, he has those jumps in the ranks.

Comment: Try this ans https://stackoverflow.com/a/44543420/8089770

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give space between gridview in through java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543234/how-to-give-space-between-gridview-in-through-java)

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/grid"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:numColumns="2"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
   android:verticalScrollbarPosition="right"
   android:scrollbars="vertical">
</GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add empty data into list

```
ArrayList<Data> list=new ArrayList<Data>
list.add(new Data(G13));
list.add(new Data(G23));
list.add(new Data(0);//set id=0
list.add(new Data(G43));
```

In adapter getView()

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {  
    if(list.get(position).getId().equals("0")){//empty data
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
    }else{
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try my solution,**

Show stroke in between gridview layout rows and columns programmatically

> Showing border between grid view items separate the [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)
>   items so each and every item looks individually. In this tutorial we
>   are creating a custom string array and setting up that string array
>   into grid view using array adapter class. Now we are dynamically
>   creating [textview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) for each string element and set that element
>   inside gird view one by one. So here is the complete step by step
>   tutorial for How to display divider/border between [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) items
>   in Android.

**Code for MainActivity.java file**

```
       public class MainActivity extends Activity {

         GridView gridView;
         List<String> ItemsList;
         String[] itemsName = new String[]{
         "ONE", "TWO", "THREE", "FOUR", "FIVE", "SIX", "SEVEN", "EIGHT","NINE"};
         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
         ItemsList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(itemsName));
         gridView.setAdapter(new TextAdapter(this));
         }

         private class TextAdapter extends BaseAdapter
         {
         Context context;
         public TextAdapter(Context context) 
         {
         this.context = context;
         }

         @Override
         public int getCount() {

         return itemsName.length;
         }

         @Override
         public Object getItem(int position) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return itemsName[position];
         }

         @Override
         public long getItemId(int position) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return position;
         }

         @Override
         public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         TextView text = new TextView(this.context);
         text.setText(itemsName[position]);
         text.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
         text.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fbdcbb"));
         text.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(144, 144));
         text.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.grid_items_border);

         return text;
          }
         }
        }

**Code for activity_main.xml layout file**

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
 android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
 tools:context="com.gridviewwithborder_android_examples.com.MainActivity">

 <GridView
 android:id="@+id/gridView1"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
 android:numColumns="3" >
 </GridView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Code for grid_items_border.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  
 <solid android:color="#fafbfb" />
 <stroke
 android:width="2dp"
 android:color="#fd0261" ></stroke>
</shape>
```

**Screeshot:**

[image]